# Concurrency using static variables

Tags: c#, concurrency, static

In the code below, if the `GetNextNumber()` is called by two threads concurrently is possible that it returns same number to both the threads?

```
class Counter
{
 private static int s_Number = 0;
 public static int GetNextNumber()
 {
  s_Number++;
  return s_Number;
 }
}
```

Can you explain why?

EDIT: If it is possible for the code to return same number to both threads then is the following correct?  Let's say the two threads call `GetNextNumber()` when `s_Number` is equal to 2. If the same value is returned then that value can only by 4. It cannot be 3. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: It's possible, though not guaranteed

Comment: It's unlikely, but because it's possible you should handle the situation. I would use the lock keyword.

Comment: unlikely but possible. maybe you should add [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] to your method

Comment: Come on guys! If you say "it is possible.." please suggest informations to him which provide your opinions..

Comment: Okay, so let's say the two threads access it when s_Number is equal to 2. If the same value is returned then that value can only by 4. It cannot be 3. Is that correct?

Comment: Not so, look at the IL code generated for your class.

Comment: @Steve can you show a scenario in answers below, how can the code return 3 to both the calling threads?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When dealing with such a simple counter, it's best to use [`Interlocked.Increment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx):

```
private static int s_Number = 0;

public static int GetNextNumber()
{
    return Interlocked.Increment(ref s_Number);
}
```

This will ensure each thread will return a unique value (as long as the number doesn't overflow), and that no increments will be lost.

Since the original code can be broken down into these steps:

1. Read the existing value of `s_Number`
2. Add 1 to it
3. Store the new value into `s_Number`
4. Read `s_Number`
5. Return the read value

The scenarios that can occur are:

1. Both threads execute step 1 before the rest, which means both threads will read the same existing value, increment by 1, ending up on the same value. **Lost an increment**
2. The threads can execute step 1 through 3 without conflict, but end up executing step 4 after both threads have updated the variable, retrieving the same value. **Skipped a number**

For larger pieces of code, where more data needs to be accessed *atomically*, a `lock` statement is usually a better way:

```
private readonly object _SomeLock = new object();

...

lock (_SomeLock)
{
    // only 1 thread allowed in here at any one time
    // manipulate the data structures here
}
```

But for such a simple piece of code, where all you need to do is atomically increment a field and retrieve the new value, `Interlocked.Increment` is better, faster, less code.

There are other methods on the [`Interlocked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kczs5b5.aspx) class as well, they're really handy in the scenarios they handle.

More detailed explanation of *lost an increment*.

Let's assume that `s_Number` starts at 0 before the two threads execute:

```
Thread 1                            Thread 2
Read s_Number = 0
                                    Read s_Number = 0
Add 1 to s_Number, getting 1
                                    Add 1 to s_Number, getting 1 (same as thread 1)
Store into s_Number (now 1)
                                    Store into s_Number (now 1)
Read s_Number = 1
                                    Read s_Number = 1
Return read value (1)
                                    Return read value (1)
```

As you can see above, the final value of `s_Number` should've been 2, and one of the threads should've returned 1, the other 2. Instead the final value was 1, and both threads returned 1. You lost an increment here.

Detailed explanation of skipping a number

```
Thread 1                            Thread 2
Read s_Number = 0
Add 1 to s_Number, getting 1
Store into s_Number (now 1)
                                    Read s_Number = 1
                                    Add 1 to s_Number, getting 2
                                    Store into s_Number (now 2)
Read s_Number = 2
                                    Read s_Number = 2
Return read value (2)
                                    Return read value (2)
```

Here the final result of `s_Number` will be 2, which is correct, but one of the threads should've returned 1, instead they both returned 2.

Let's see how the original code looks on an IL level. I'll add the original code into the IL instructions with comments

```
// public static int GetNumber()
// {
GetNumber:
//     s_Number++;
IL_0000:  ldsfld      UserQuery.s_Number    // step 1: Read s_Number
IL_0005:  ldc.i4.1                          // step 2: Add 1 to it
IL_0006:  add                               //         (part of step 2)
IL_0007:  stsfld      UserQuery.s_Number    // step 3: Store into s_Number
// return s_Number;
IL_000C:  ldsfld      UserQuery.s_Number    // step 4: Read s_Number
IL_0011:  ret                               // step 5: Return the read value
// }
```

Note, I used [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) to get the IL code above, enabling optimizations (small /o+ in the lower right corner), if you want to play with the code to see how it converts into IL, download LINQPad and feed it this program:

```
void Main() { } // Necessary for LINQPad/Compiler to be happy

private static int s_Number = 0;
public static int GetNumber()
{
    s_Number++;
    return s_Number;
}
```

Comment: @Lasse +1 for the scenarios. Can you explain the Lost scenario? The line I'm taking is: since s_Number is a value on the stack, as long as it's incremented twice, it cannot have lost increment.

Comment: okay, got it. I forgot that every thread gets its own separate stack and the value type is copied.

Comment: I outlined everything in more detail, please refresh

Answer (score 8):

Yes, here is a scenario :

s_number = 0

`Thread A` do `s_number ++`

s_number = 1

`Thread B` do `s_number ++`

s_number = 2

`Thread A` do `return s_number`

`Thread B` do `return s_number`

Both threads returned 2.

---

Therefore, you should implement a locking mechanism like this :

```
class Counter
{
    private static int s_Number = 0;
    private static object _locker = new object();
    public static int GetNextNumber()
    {
        //Critical section
        return Interlocked.Increment(ref s_Number);
    }
}
```

The locking mechanism will prevent multiple threads to enter your critical section at the same time. If you have more operation than a simple increment, use a `Lock` block instead.

Edit: A more in-depth answer has been written by Lasse V. Karlsen, explaining more low-level behaviours.

Comment: +1, although in this situation I'd probably use [`Interlocked.Increment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.increment.aspx) rather than a full `lock`.

Comment: @Luke Marlin, thanks. However I know how to fix the problem. What I'm interested in is the reason why.

Comment: @bytefire added a mini scenario for this

Comment: @LukeH indeed, that sounds like a better solution. I didn't knew it, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see why it is possible to get the same number when two threads try to access the concurrently the `GetNextNumber` method if we look at `IL code` generated for your class method

```
class Counter
{
    private static int s_Number = 0;
    public static int GetNextNumber()
    {
        s_Number++;
        return s_Number;
    }
}
```

Here below the IL Code generated, and, as you can see, the `s_number++` is really composed by three separate instructions that could be accessed concurrently by two thread and thus getting the same initial value.

```
Counter.GetNextNumber:
IL_0000:  ldsfld      UserQuery+Counter.s_Number
IL_0005:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0006:  add         
IL_0007:  stsfld      UserQuery+Counter.s_Number
IL_000C:  ldsfld      UserQuery+Counter.s_Number
IL_0011:  ret
```

**This is the SCENARIO that leads to the same value for both threads**

The `thread A` enters and get the value of s_Number (IL_0000), it loads the value 1 but, at this point, the processor suspend the `thread A` and starts the `thread B`. Of course the value stored in the memory location defined for `s_number` is still 0 and the thread B start with the same value used byt thread A. It gets back 1. When thread A resumes its registers are restored as they were at the suspension time, so it adds 1 to 0 and gets back the same result of thread B.

This class use the lock keyword to block the concurrency

```
class CounterLocked
{
 private static object o;
 private static int s_Number = 0;
 public static int GetNextNumber()
 {
  lock(o)
  {
    s_Number++;
    return s_Number;
  }
 }
}

CounterLocked.GetNextNumber:
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0001:  stloc.0     // <>s__LockTaken0
IL_0002:  ldsfld      UserQuery+CounterLocked.o
IL_0007:  dup         
IL_0008:  stloc.2     // CS$2$0001
IL_0009:  ldloca.s    00 // <>s__LockTaken0
IL_000B:  call        System.Threading.Monitor.Enter
IL_0010:  ldsfld      UserQuery+CounterLocked.s_Number
IL_0015:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0016:  add         
IL_0017:  stsfld      UserQuery+CounterLocked.s_Number
IL_001C:  ldsfld      UserQuery+CounterLocked.s_Number
IL_0021:  stloc.1     // CS$1$0000
IL_0022:  leave.s     IL_002E
IL_0024:  ldloc.0     // <>s__LockTaken0
IL_0025:  brfalse.s   IL_002D
IL_0027:  ldloc.2     // CS$2$0001
IL_0028:  call        System.Threading.Monitor.Exit
IL_002D:  endfinally  
IL_002E:  ldloc.1     // CS$1$0000
IL_002F:  ret
```

The code generated for the InterlockIncrement is very simple

```
public static int GetNextNumber()
{
    return Interlocked.Increment(ref s_Number);
}

CounterLocked.GetNextNumber:
IL_0000:  ldsflda     UserQuery+CounterLocked.s_Number
IL_0005:  call        System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment
IL_000A:  ret
```

Comment: That's very helpful. Can you see the new EDIT section of my question please?

Answer (score 0):

return Interlocked.Increment(ref s_Number);

This will do it. It's much simpler than using lock. Locking blocks should mainly be used for blocks of code, usually.